# an unclear problem related to the work of qsqlquery, namely with the query.value() command

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qsqlquery

When running this program code, it is concluded that the database is connected, as well as that the dimension of query = 2, after which an error occurs when trying to call the guery.value function. The Segmentation Fault error, why it happens is unclear. I need help. Here is the program code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", "cash");
db.setConnectOptions("requiressl=1;connect_timeout=2");
db.setHostName("rdbmsastra.vt");
db.setPort(5432);
db.setDatabaseName("cvcomputer");
db.setUserName("astra");
db.setPassword("123451");
db.open();
if (db.isOpen()){
    qDebug() << "Success open DB";
} else qDebug() << "FAIL" << db.lastError().text();

QSqlQuery query("select * from status", db);
qDebug() << query.size();
while(query.next()){
    qDebug() << query.value("id_s").toInt();
    qDebug() << query.value("discription").toString();
}
```

programming takes place on windows 10 in qt creator.

I hope for your help

Comment: When it crashes then you get a backtrace which you should take a look on to see why and where it crashes exactly.

Comment: Try to check what `query.value("id_s")` and `query.value("discription")` return. It should be a valid `QVariant` object.